# Run code after transcluded code is linked in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive with transclude and when link is executed I always have `{{ }}` when I try to do jQuery with $element. I have html like this:

```
<outter>
  <inner ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}">
    {{item.name}}
  </inner>
</outter>
```

and inside `inner` link function when I run

```
console.log($element.html());
```

I've got `<li ng-repeat="item in items"><a>{{item.name}}</a></li>` (my template is `<li><a>`).

inside outter $element in link function there is one `ng-repeat`

I need to initialize my directive when everything is in place. Is there there a way to do this in Angular? I've try post link (but I think is the same as just link) also transclude using a function. and everytime I got template that's not interpolated even that scope is updated, they are never in sync.

In my code (not in demo) I'm using ngModelController and $render is also rendered before everything is updated.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Y7qtjRuMa4iRITzNx2V)

Comment: `$timeout` might be the only choice.